# TypeError: Cannot set property 'message' of undefined using express validator

Tags: node.js, ejs, express-validator

I am trying to set validation of an array using express validator and ejs method and I keep getting the error that says

```
C:\Users\ADLIMITED\Desktop\favourite\node_modules\express-validator\src\chain\validators-impl.js:25
        this.lastValidator.message = message;
                                   ^
TypeError: Cannot set property 'message' of undefined
    at ValidatorsImpl.withMessage (C:\Users\ADLIMITED\Desktop\favourite\node_modules\express-validator\src\chain\validators-impl.js:25:36)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\ADLIMITED\Desktop\favourite\routes\index.js:35:33)
```

this is the array that contains the validation methods:

```
router.post(
    '/contact',
    [
      check('name').trim().isLength({ min: 3 }).escape().withMessage('A name is required'),
      check('email').trim().isEmail().normalizeEmail().withMessage('A valid email is required'),
      check('service').escape().withMessage('Select a service'),
      check('budget').escape().withMessage('Choose a budget'),
      check('message').trim().isLength({ min: 3 }).escape().withMessage('Leave us a message'),
    ],
    (req, res) => {
      const errors = validationResult(req);
      if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
        req.session.feedbackContact = {
          errors: errors.array(),
        };
        return res.redirect('/contact');
      }
      console.log(req.body);
      return res.send('feedback form posted');
    }
  );
```

and the html page with the details to be validated alongside the error msg

```
<div class="container-content100">
  <div class="content-wrapper100">
    <% if(locals.errors) {%>
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
      <% errors.forEach(function(error){ %>
      <li><% error.msg %></li>
      <% }) %>
    </div>
    <% } %>

    <form class="" method="POST" action="/contact">
```

Please help

Answer (score 1):

I found my mistake where I was assigning .withMessage to option input and the ejs page was meant to have the assignment symbol in the list element otherwise the message wouldn't show up.
The right code looks like down below:

**the array that contains the validation methods:**

```
'/contact',
    [
      check('name').trim().isLength({ min: 3 }).escape().withMessage('A name is required'),
      check('email').trim().isEmail().normalizeEmail().withMessage('A valid email is required'),
      check('service').escape(),
      check('budget').escape(),
      check('message').trim().isLength({ min: 3 }).escape().withMessage('Leave us a message'),
    ],
```

**the html page with the details to be validated alongside the error msg**

```
<div class="container-content100">
  <div class="content-wrapper100">
    <% if(locals.errors) {%>
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
      <% errors.forEach(function(error){ %>
      <li><%= error.msg %></li>
      <% }) %>
    </div>
    <% } %>

    <form class="" method="POST" action="/contact">
```

Answer (score 1):

I had that error, when in a validation chain I tried to chain a .optional() method with a .withMessage() method.

I had the following:

```
body("email")
.optional()
.withMessage("Enter a valid email") // this causes the error
```

So I removed the .withMessage method:

```
body("email")
.optional()
```